# Stein's Lemma for Multivariate Gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, expected-value, integral

Is there a version of Stein's lemma for multivariate Gaussians, I am attempting to solve integrals of the form:

$$
\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{x} g(\mathbf{x})) =\int_{\mathbb{R}^p} \mathbf{x} g(\mathbf{x}) \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}| \mu, \Sigma) d\mathbf{x}
$$

and

$$
\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x} g(\mathbf{x}))
$$

where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^p$ is a Gaussian vector with mean $\mu$, and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^p \to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Lemma 1 from [Liu](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/df6c/a13b1494fd1c659f7190b9d06fd5a5de1828.pdf) is probably what you want.

Comment: Yes, see lemma 6.20 (page 74) in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.02180) for a more general version that does not require the covariance matrix to be the identity matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an exercise from [my book](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw):

> If $x\sim\mathcal{N}(\theta,1)$ and $f$ is continuous and a.e.
>   differentiable, then $$ \mathbb{E}_\theta[(x-\theta)f(x)]  = 
>  \mathbb{E}_\theta[f'(x)]. $$ Deduce that, if $x\sim
>  \mathcal{N}_p(\theta,\Sigma)$, $\delta(x) = x+\Sigma\gamma(x)$, and
>   $\mathrm{L}(\theta,\delta) = (\delta-\theta)^tQ(\delta-\theta)$, with
>   $\gamma$ differentiable, then $$ R(\theta,\delta)  =
>  \mathbb{E}_\theta\left[{\mathrm{tr}}(Q\Sigma)+2\,{\mathrm{tr}}(J_\gamma(x)Q^*)+
>  \gamma(x)^tQ^*\gamma(x)\right], $$ where ${\mathrm{tr}}(A)$ is the
>   trace of $A$, $Q^* = \Sigma Q\Sigma$ and $J_\gamma(x)$ is the matrix
>   with generic element ${\partial \over \partial x_i}\gamma_j(x)$.

which implies in particular that
$$\mathbb{E}_\theta[(\mathbf{X}-\theta)^\text{T} g(\mathbf{X})] =\mathbb{E}_\theta[\nabla^\text{T} g(\mathbf{X})]$$
in the case of an identity covariance matrix.

Comment: Shouldn't we have the covariance matrix somewhere in the expression? Also shouldn't the expectations in the last line be with respect to $X$ rather than $\theta$ ?

Comment: I think what you've got there is the case with identity covariance

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{E}_\theta$ means that the expectation depends on $\theta$, i.e., that the distribution of the rv $\mathbf{X}$ depends on $\theta$, not that $\theta$ _is_ the random variable.

Comment: if you could please update to provide a version of Stein's Lemma for the general covariance case, or provide a reference, that would be appreciated

Comment: I do not understand what role $R(\theta,\delta)$ and $L(\theta,\delta)$ play here, so it is hard for me to see how the exercise implies the given relation.